# MySql 5.6 and missing libmemcached.so

Tags: mysql, libmemcached

After update Mysql 5.5 to 5.6 on debian I want start using memchached. In /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ i do not see libmemcached.so plugin. How i can install this plugin and use?

Answer (score 0):

It does not come as a part of it. You have to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install/update mysql server using the official repository. This way you will have some tools and plugins (such libmemcached.so) installed. I've done it already doing these simple steps:

1. Download and install the repo: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
2. Switch from debian to official repository and install mysql server 5.6: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-replacing
3. You should now have available the libmemcache.so file within the plugins folder and should be able to proceed with the installation of the plugin.